# popover is not hiding when click on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i m trying to fix a popover on an image click i m trying to do something like in the way that if i click on the image the popover shows if i agian click the image it hides, but i want something more if i click out of the image and popover it sholud be hide any help would be appriciated, thanks.

```
$("#popup-img").click(function () {

    if ($(".popup").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".popup").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
    if ($(".popup").is(":visible")) {
        // i thin here code should be if i click out of the popover 
        // it should be hide again
    }
});
```

Comment: you are writing code to hide popup, inside the click handler of the popupimage and you want to hide the popupimage, while clicked elsewhere??

Comment: yes, i want it when i click elsewhere in the document the popup[ shuold hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using bootstrap as indicated by the tag this is very simple since bootstrap provides this functionality by default:

**HTML**

```
<div id="popup-img"> Click</div>
<div class="popup modal hide">This is a popup</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#popup-img").click(function(){
    $(".popup").modal();
});
```

Comment: yes i m using bootstrap, and i have also addd bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js, but it was not working ,Therefore i decided to do it with jquery seperately.

Comment: @Shahbaz did you add `.modal` to the popup?

Comment: i have also added modal in the popup

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#popup-img").click(function () {

    if ($(".popup").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".popup").slideDown("fast");
    }
});
$(window).click(function () {

    if ($(".popup").is(": visible")) {
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work whenc i click on it closes without clicking anywhere

Comment: So add your else{...} on img click

Comment: can you add your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
$("#popup-img").click(function () {
    $(".popup").slideDown("fast");
    $("body").click(function() {
        $(this).unbind("click");
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work whenc i click on it closes without clicking anywhere